# How do you turn on hotkeys in Coursera video player?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, video, coursera

I like to see lectures [like reading, with regressions and tempo variation](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/13725). This is done by hotkeys, which are especially important in full screen mode, which is also advisable because even fewer controls are available in this mode. But, unfortunately, player has no reaction on hitting the button despite the information bar saying explicitly which are supported (you should be able to show/hide it with <kbd>H</kbd> key).

Answer (score 6):

Right click on the video and select "Show Controls".

Then you can go backwards and forwards by 15 s with the arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

If by hotkeys you talk about keyboard shortcuts. I have found something for Firefox in Coursera.

By default, the shortcuts work on Youtube but not on Coursera. However, if you click right on the video and select "*show the controls*", then the shortcuts work.

[Mozilla support: Shortcuts for Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/html5-audio-and-video-firefox#w_keyboard-controls)

Note: sometimes it stops working and I have to hide again then show again the controls.

Answer (score 2):

For me in Chrome it pauses with "K".

Answer (score 2):

## Not Supported Natively

I do not know a way to jump forward or back using the native Coursera video player controls while in full-screen mode.

The arrow-based shortcuts that are supported natively by Coursera don't work if the video is playing in full-screen mode <sup>***** See **Coursera's Native KBD Shortcuts** below</sup>

I contacted Coursera's customer support about the issue and received a reply that included:

> I will pass along this feedback for our team to take it into consideration for future improvements. Thank you for being part of our community and helping us grow.

I can't believe that we are still dealing with this problem almost nine years after the original post. Thanks for everyone's input.

## Workaround

As a workaround, I use the Chrome browser extension **[Video Speed Controller](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-speed-controller/nffaoalbilbmmfgbnbgppjihopabppdk)** which enables **<kbd>Z</kbd>** and **<kbd>X</kbd>** to jump backward and forward in 10-second increments while in full-screen mode for any HTML5 video including Coursera's.

The extension also supports changing the video playback speed, along with several other handy features.

> **Chromium:**  [Chrome Web Store > Video Speed Controller](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/video-speed-controller/nffaoalbilbmmfgbnbgppjihopabppdk)
> **Firefox:**    [Firefox Add-Ons > Video Speed Controller](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/videospeed/)
>
> ##### Developer's Description
>
> Speed up, slow down, advance and rewind HTML5 audio/video with shortcuts.
>
> HTML5 video provides native APIs to accelerate playback of any video,
> but most implemented players either hide or limit this functionality.
> This extension fixes that, plus more...
>
> It will help you optimize your video viewing by allowing you to make quick playback speed adjustments, as well as rewind the video to hear the last few seconds one more time. We don't read at a constant speed, and we talk much slower than we read there is no reason why we have to listen at a constant speed and at a (very) slow rate.
>
> Once the extension is installed simply navigate to any page that offers HTML5 video, and you'll see a speed indicator in top left corner of the video player. Hover over the indicator to reveal the controls to accelerate, slow down, or rewind the video (10 seconds + lowers playback speed). Or, even better, use your keyboard:
>
> - S - decrease playback speed.
> - D - increase playback speed.
> - R - reset playback speed.
> - Z - rewind video by 10 seconds.
> - X - advance video by 10 seconds.
> - V - show/hide controller.
>
> If you prefer other shortcuts, want to change the increment value, or want the player to remember your playback speed in the future, head into the settings page and customize it to your heart's content.

## Coursera's Native KBD Shortcuts

The arrow-based shortcuts, numbers 4 - 7 below, won't work if the video is playing in full-screen mode.

1. **<kbd>Space</kbd>** or **<kbd>K</kbd>** - Play/Pause the video
2. **<kbd>F</kbd>**   - Toggle full-screen mode
3. **<kbd>M</kbd>** - Mute/Unmute the video
4. **<kbd>←</kbd>** - Rewind the video by a few seconds
5. **<kbd>→</kbd>** - Fast Forward the video by a few seconds
6. **<kbd>↑</kbd>** - Increase the volume
7. **<kbd>↓</kbd>** - Decrease the volume

Comment: Your answer is complete however I edited it to focus on your current content, be less conversational, and hopefully easier to follow. I hope this gets it the additional recognition it deserves.  Please reverse any changes you don't agree with. I will remove this comment as soon as you acknowledge it.

Answer (score 1):

As I tried,

- `k` for pause
- `f` for full screen
- `m` for mute

but I cannot find any documentation for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old question and sadly the behavior is still the same, seems like in full screen mode there is an event that puts the video out of focus and that's the reason the hotkeys stop working after some time, when you're not in full screen mode this doesn't happen (you can see a blue border around the video that reflects this).

You can make a script for refocusing into the div by adding a "tabindex" and then focusing on it, I thought of making it, since the extension that was shared in one of the answers no longer exists, but right now I don't have the time, maybe some time in the future.

For now I'll share a "manual" solution I've found:

Using Firefox, while on fullscreen, press "tab" one time, that will bring the focus into the reproduction timeline, and being there it allows you to use the arrow keys to rewind or go forward, you can also use "k" for reproducing and pausing while the focus is there, when you're done press "shift+tab" to "unfocus" and hide the timeline.

I know it doesn't give all hotkeys functionality but it's something.